# find and remove multiple patterns for one string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string url, it might starts with `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://` etc.

First I need to check if the string indeed starts with the header using `url.startswith(header)` then I need to remove the header. For example, if input is `http://example.com/example` the function will check that the url starts with `http://` and return `example.com/example`.

So how to write pythonic code for this task (don't really want to use a for loop)? Or should I just use regex?

Comment: Go for regex. It will be easy to perform this kind of task using regex.

Comment: Why aren't you using [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex would be a bit of an overkill if that's all you want, just split your string on `://` and check if it starts with any of your approved protocols:

```
uri = your_string.split("://", 1)
if len(uri) > 1 and uri[0] in {"http", "https", "ftp"}:
    print("Match: " + uri[1])
else:
    print("No match!")
```

This, however, doesn't guarantee the validity of your URI so if you think your string might contain an invalid URL you'll have to use something more complex.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you use a `set` for the lookup instead of a `list` or `tuple`?

Comment: @Szabolcs - `set` is a hash table, so O(1) search complexity on average.

Comment: yet when I use timeit to compare it with `list` or `tuple` I get much better results for both.

Comment: @Szabolcs - in Python 3.x (as tagged by OP)? I very much doubt it... Even in Python 2.x it will still be faster if you don't re-create the `set` all the time (the time is spent on re-hashing the elements) which is what would one do outside of SO example code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith), you could pass `str.startswith()` a `tuple` of strings to test for:

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if string starts with the `prefix`, otherwise return `False`. **`prefix` can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.**

```
def get_url(url):
    headers = ('http://', 'https://', 'ftp://')
    if url.startswith(headers):
        url = url[url.find('://')+3:]
    return url


http = 'http://example.com/example'
https = 'https://example.com/example'
ftp = 'ftp://example.com/example'

print(get_url(http))
print(get_url(https))
print(get_url(ftp))

example.com/example
example.com/example
example.com/example
>>>
```